# JavaScript For Loop work hows?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am using JavaScript for loop, my code is here

```
content = "";           
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  var alt=glevel[i].getAttribute("name");
  if(jQuery.inArray(alt, clickArray) > -1) {
    if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 8 || $.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7) {
      content += "<li id='"+alt+"' style='cursor:pointer;filter:alpha(opacity=50);'>"+alt+"<br><div style='width:auto;'><img src='products/"+alt+".png'><br><font size='1px'>Click Base To Select</font></div><br><p style='text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;font-size:10px;margin-top:-18px;' id='"+alt+"'>Click Here For Product Info</p></li> \n";
    } else {
      content += "<li id='"+alt+"' style='cursor:pointer;opacity:0.3;'>"+alt+"<br><div style='width:auto;'><img src='products/"+alt+".png'><br><font size='1px'>Click Base To Select</font></div><br><p style='text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;font-size:10px;margin-top:-18px;' id='"+alt+"'>Click Here For Product Info</p></li> \n";
    }
    //$('#'+clickArray[alt]+"").css("opacity","0.5");
  } else{
    content += "<li id='"+alt+"' style='cursor:pointer'>"+alt+"<br><div style='width:auto;'><img src='products/"+alt+".png'><br><font size='1px'></font></div><br><p style='text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;font-size:10px;margin-top:-18px;' id='"+alt+"'></p></li> \n";
  }
  $("#step_2").html(content);
}
```

output of this code is something like that :-

```
image1 image2 image3 image4 
image5 image6 
image7 image8 image9 image10 
image11 image12 image13

update:- it looks like that because of my table width and height
```

It works very fine, it display the real product images what i have.

now i want to display something like this :-

```
image1 image2 image3 image4     
image5 image6 image7     
image8 image9 image10     
image11 image12 image13
```

means in the first row 4 images, while 2nd,3rd, and 4th row have 3 images

Comment: How is this 5/4/4 pattern achieved in the first place?

Comment: your code looks really terrible. Don't use inline styles. Don't use font-tags. Dont use those `<br>`

Comment: @Amberlamps :) because of my table width

Comment: well, then adjust your table width so it displays 4/3/3 instead of 5/4/4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    content += "...";

    if (i == 3)                       // after the fourth line,
       content += '<br/><br/>';       // add an empty line
    if (i > 3 && (i - 4) % 3 == 2)    // then, after every three lines
       content += '<br/><br/>';       // add an empty line
}
```

Comment: I really like your logic, amazing! the only thing I would change is to add a `continue;` to remove the `i > 3` check and add a check to don't add breaks on the `i == 12` http://jsfiddle.net/cQzgD/

Comment: I don't no why but i think because of my table width, it displays the same data again after using you logic

Comment: @ajax333221 Well, you're right that `i > 3` is actually not necessary. It is only there to prevent the newline from being added at `i == 2`, but that won't happen because `(2 - 4) % 3 == -2`, not `2` :) The `continue`, however, only spares one `if` comparison, so that's not that much of an efficiency improvement.

Comment: @ajax333221 And yes, `i != 12` will be probably nicer for what op wants. I wanted to solve the task generally, though :)

Comment: well not much performance now, but if he keep adding stuff below that line it will get worse. Also, about the efficiency of `%` vs two loops: http://jsperf.com/loopcomparation (I know is not 100% your code, but it should be the same results)

Comment: @ajax333221 Indeed, `%` is an expensive operation. I once found out and was amazed about how much faster `while (x > n) x -= n;` is than `x %= n` in Java, if `x` is only a bit larger than `n` (say, `x` < `3n`).

Comment: however, if one must do it using the `%`, why not simply `if(i%3==0)` (but skipping on `i==0` or `i==12`) http://jsfiddle.net/cQzgD/1/ I am starting to don't like your logic...

Comment: @ajax333221 Yes, that can be done too. There are actually quite many ways, how to accomplish this. However, as I said, I was thinking rather generally and wanted to write my code generally. My code can be easily modified for any task of the type: "`a` items in the first row, `b` items in every other row".

Answer (score 1):

This is could do the trick:

```
var content = "", imgNum = 1, max = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
        max = 3;
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < max; j++) {
        content += "image" + imgNum;
        imgNum++;
    }
    content += "<br />";
}

document.write(content);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xj5S8/)

This is the logic:

- set starting image number to 1
- set max to 4 (later we will change it to 3)
- loop the num of rows (4 times)

  - if we are at the first loop, leave max 4, otherwise change it to 3
  - loop the num of cols (max times)

    - add stuff to content
    - increase image number by 1
  - add the break after the loop

I prefered to use two loops instead of using the `%` operator, because it is more readable and faster.

edit: If you don't care about performance, I found a way to make a readable version with the `%`:

```
var content="";

for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++){
    content += "image"+(i+1);
    if(i==0||i==12){
        continue;
    }
    if(i%3==0) {
        content += "<br />";
    }
}

document.write(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

put this at the end of loop:

```
if (i == 3) { content += '<br/>'; }
if (i > 3 && (i - 4) % 3 == 2) { content += '<br/>'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++){
    content += "<li>...</li>";
    if(i==3 || i==6 || i==9) { content += "<br />"; }
}
```