# var i returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to retrieve my database values and insert them into a table.

I am trying to iterate `i` onto an array.

However, it returns undefined and there is no output. Why is this so?

Could it be an issue with the script or the body tag?

Script

```
function getitemdetails() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = serverURL() + "/mycasefeed.php";
  url += "?Case_ID=" + decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["Case_ID"]);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      getitemResult(xmlhttp.responseText);
    };
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function getitemResult(response) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(response);
  var i;


    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    $("#mycase").append("<tr><td>" + arr[i].CaseDes +
    arr[i].Case_Pic +
    "<br>" + arr[i].categoryname +
    "<br>" + arr[i].Caselat +
    "<br>" + arr[i].Caselong +
    "<br>" + arr[i].CaseTime +
    "<br>" + arr[i].details + "</td></tr>");
}
$("#mycaseresult").table("refresh");
}

getitemdetails();
```

Body

```
<div id="SearchResult" class="ui-content">
  <table data-role="table" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive" id="mycaseresult">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        *insert values here*
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="mycase">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's your code `var i; alert(i);`. Why do you expect `i` to have a value?

Comment: you dont instantiate i you just initialise it and then do nothing with it?

Comment: `var i; alert(i);` - You have just declared `i`, it has no value so you see `undefined`

Comment: Solution to your question - [definition of undefined in JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp)

Comment: Also look at [JavaScript for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585745/javascript-for-loop-work-hows) or [jQuery each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364031/jquery-each-objects)

Answer (score 1):

the reason it is returned undefined is because the variable has no content.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, any empty variable (declared, but not defined) is `undefined`.

```
var a;
var b = {};

function foo(parameter) {
    console.log(parameter);
}

console.log(a); // Outputs: `undefined`
console.log(b.cool); // Outputs: `undefined`
foo(); // Outputs: `undefined`
```

On your code, looks like you are trying to iterate on an array, but you don't have any iteration loop.

Try:

```
function getitemResult(response) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(response);
  for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      $("#mycase").append("<tr><td>" + arr[i].CaseDes +
          arr[i].Case_Pic +
          "<br>" + arr[i].categoryname +
          "<br>" + arr[i].Caselat +
          "<br>" + arr[i].Caselong +
          "<br>" + arr[i].CaseTime +
          "<br>" + arr[i].details + "</td></tr>");
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried to insert your code but I still do not get an output